# AWS deleted Network Interface from RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, network-interface

I was cleaning up Network Interfaces in AWS that looked like they weren't being used (Status was available and weren't tied to an Instance ID) so I deleted them. I received no warning that they were attached to an RDS instance like I would if it was attached to an EC2 Instance. So now all my RDS instances are failing "Database instance in incompatible-network... Customer ENI does not exist... The networkInterfaceID does not exist."

I recreated a Network Interface but I can only Attach it to an EC2 Instance, there is no option to attach it to an RDS instance.

What is the workaround for this? If I create a new RDS, have it automatically create a new Network Interface, I will be able to Detach it, but my only option to Attach will again be to an EC2 Instance, not an RDS instance.

Comment: Contact AWS support, they're the only ones who can help you in this situation

Answer (score 0):

In the upper right side of the instance there is a button that says "Modify". Once there you can change some things like if you were creating again the RDS instance.

To be more specific in you case, after you go to the "modify" part, there is a section "Network & Security", once there you can specify the network you want to use.

Comment: On an active RDS I see Modify > Network & Security but I can only attach a Security Group. I don't see any place to specify a Network Interface directly.

On a broken RDS I see Modify > "Database name is currently not in a modifiable state" so that option isn't available. Appreciate you helping me troubleshoot this.